# JPA2 / Hibernate query: using Date as a query param ignoring the "time" part

Tags: hibernate, date, jpa, criteria

I want to select some records of a criteria query based on a date field:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
Root<Macchinario> from = cq.from(Macchinario.class);
cq.select(from);

cq.where(
                    cb.and(
                        cb.like(from.<String>get("marca"), "%"+ricerca.getMarca()+"%"),
                        cb.like(from.<String>get("modello"), "%"+ricerca.getModello()+"%"),
                        cb.like(from.<String>get("matricola"), "%"+ricerca.getMatricola()+"%"),

                        cb.equal(from.get("dataInserimento"), ricerca.getDataInserimento())
                    )
                );
```

dataInserimento is a java.util.Date

The "Macchinario" I'm looking for has "2012-05-23 10:16:00" in the db.

ricerca.getDataInserimento() returns "2012-05-23 00:00:00".

How can I pass that parameter, telling jpa to ignore the "time part" of the Date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>You could write an util and use it to truncate the time part from the date:</strike>

**DateHelper.java**

```
public static Date getDateWithoutTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

And then change

```
cb.equal(from.get("dataInserimento"), ricerca.getDataInserimento())
```

to

```
cb.equal(from.get("dataInserimento"), 
         DateHelper.getDateWithoutTime(ricerca.getDataInserimento()))
```

## Update

Truncating time part from the value we get from db seems impossible to do with out-of-box functionality provided by JPA or Hibernate. Hibernate provide extraction of year, month and day values from the date column though, which we are going to make us of.

```
Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dateCalendar.setTime(ricerca.getDataInserimento());

Path<Date> dataInserimento = from.get("dataInserimento");
Predicate timelessPredicate = cb.and(
        cb.equal(cb.function("year", Integer.class, dataInserimento), dateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)),
        cb.equal(cb.function("month", Integer.class, dataInserimento), dateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1),
        cb.equal(cb.function("day", Integer.class, dataInserimento), dateCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE)));

cq.where(..., timelessPredicate);
```

What we did here, we compared year, month and day values from database with provided input date separately with help of hibernate functions and calendar power.

This will do the trick.

Comment: uhmm..... I think you did not understand. My ricerca.getDataInserimento() already returns a datetime with (00:00:00) as time part. Record in db still has '10:16:00'. So how can the comparison returns a "found" result, as it compares different Dates? I need to do a comparison AVOIDING comparing time parts

Comment: It DOES the trick but..... very tricky :) I can't believe all that work for such a common query. Your answer would be perfect with a JPQL alternative query ;) Thank you

Comment: Come to think of it.. You could just expressed that with where date >= selectedDate and date < selectedDate +1day (without time parts)..

Answer (score 0):

You can try formatting date to ignore the time part by using appropriate pattern.

```
public String getDate(java.util.Date date){

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

Now, you can have date as string in proper format & then compare them for equality.

```
cb.equal(getDate(from.<java.util.Date>get("dataInserimento")), getDate(ricerca.getDataInserimento()))
```